# Spring Boot how to return custom error message when validating @PathVariable parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

Is it possible to add some custom validation message to path variable?

I have some GET

```
  @GetMapping("/v2/tw/{id}")
    public TwDto getTw(Authentication auth, @PathVariable Long id) {
```

In case of `/v2/tw/someString` I'd like to catch error and add some custom error message like "invalid tw ID"... How to do that? In `ControllerAdvice` add some `ExceptionHandler`?

Comment: Have you tried to overload the method? Create a new method (use what you showed above) and change the @PathVariable from a Long to a String in the new method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your particular use case, you can use `@ExceptionHandler` in the Controller or in a `@ControllerAdvice` class as shown here. For example, I am returning NOT_FOUND error for the sake of it.

```
@ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "this is the reason")
public void handle() {
}
```

You may not see the `reason` in the actual error response, until you enable

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
```

If you think your `@ExceptionHandler` is only needed in a Controller class you can keep the method inside the controller. Alternatively you can create a `@ControllerAdvice` class and put the method there, so that you can reuse across multiple controllers in your application.

---

However, if you want a more complex validation, I will suggest to keep the `id` type to String and then cast manually into Long and perform the validation. Doing so you can throw your own RuntimeException and handle different cases.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not reaching my ControllerAdvice with MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException... Why?